# how to customize the dragging session of NSTableView

Tags: objective-c, macos, tableview

I customize a `NSTableView`, and customize cellview based on view with the red backgroundcolor and a image.

for example:

[image]

The table implement the method:

```
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView draggingSession:     (NSDraggingSession *)session willBeginAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint     forRowIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes
```

I want to customize the drag item only be the image without the backgroudcolor.
so i wrote the code like this:

```
[session enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions:NSDraggingItemEnumerationConcurrent
    forView:tableView
    classes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSPasteboardItem class]]
    searchOptions:nil
    usingBlock:^(NSDraggingItem *draggingItem, NSInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
        [draggingItem setDraggingFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, StickerTableViewWidth, StickerTableViewHeight)
            contents:[NSImage imageNamed:imageName]];
}];
```

but in fact it does not into the block.

is there anybody know why?

Comment: How did you check it doesn't into the block?

Comment: @willeke I add a log in the block, but it did not print.

Comment: I tried this and it works except for the location of the image. The problem is probably somewhere in code you didn't show.

Comment: I tried this again, and it works inexplicably. I did not changed the code, but it works(￣▽￣)

Comment: But there is still a problem :when I setDraggingFrame, I found the coordinate is not the window or the view, the origin is (0,0), but when I drag the image, the draggingImage is shown on the left and outside the window. Can you help me, thanks very much^ - ^

Comment: @Willeke thanks for your help, I found the last two comment I didn't @you..-_-# . there is still a problem in my tableview code, could you help me, thanks very much. The link is http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34129617/customize-nstableview-dragging-session-but-dragging-frame-coordinate-is-not-the

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason I draw the red background color is 
the designer ask me to draw a a mask view over the cell view to indicate the selected status.
But the tableView is also implemented the dragging source, so when I drag the cell, the mask view is also be dragged out.

Then I googled and find we can use table row view to draw the selected status. So the problem is be solved.

But I still dont know why the block is not be implemented.
So if anybody knows please post the answer, thanks very much.