# Customize NSTableView dragging session but dragging frame coordinate is not the tableview?

Tags: objective-c, macos, tableview

```
-(void)tableView:(NSTableView *)tableView
 draggingSession: (NSDraggingSession *)session
willBeginAtPoint:(NSPoint)screenPoint
   forRowIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes {
  [session enumerateDraggingItemsWithOptions:NSDraggingItemEnumerationConcurrent
                                 forView:tableView
                                 classes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSPasteboardItem class]]
                           searchOptions:nil
                              usingBlock:^(NSDraggingItem *draggingItem, NSInteger index, BOOL *stop) {
                                NSImage *image = [NSImage imageNamed:@"about_bg"];

                                [draggingItem setDraggingFrame:NSMakeRect(0, 0, 100, 100)
                                                      contents:image];
                              }];
```

}

[image]

just like the picture shows, the location of dragging picture is not the mouse point location. 
Dose anybody know why? Thanks for help~~^_^

Comment: The frame of the original image is in `[draggingItem draggingFrame]`.

Comment: @Willeke thanks very much, you help me a lot. ☆*:.｡. o(≧▽≦)o .｡.:*☆

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the reason of this problem is my poor english, I didn't understand the apple doc completely. and thanks @Willeke for the help.
what I should do is not to change the dragging frame. So just set [draggingItem draggingFrame] to draggingFrame.(￣▽￣) 
I think this is a very stupid question, haha~~